# sending dynamic memory from function to the user. How to deallocate it?

Tags: java

i am basically from C/C++ background. Sorry to ask very basic question. I have written a function like the following:

```
  public ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList()
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> keys = myHashTable.keySet();
        for(Integer key: keys) {
            arrList.add(key);
        }

        return arrList;
    }
```

User can invoke `myArrayList()` Multiple times, and how do i have to address the user to deallocate the memory for `arrList` ?.

Comment: Forget about deallocate the memory in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the garbage collector takes care of deallocating memory once it is not used any more. So, as soon as the last reference to the ArrayList object you returned leaves its scope, the object is marked as unused, and its memory will be released on the next run of the garbage collector.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any way to explicitly free the memory?

Comment: No, there isn't. Why would you want to do that? You can explicitly trigger the garbage collector with System.gc(), but that would be rather unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about memory management, Java does this for you.